# What happens if a bounty question is never answered?

Tags: discussion, bounties

The following question for example: [Coupon calculates but doesn't sent correct amount to payment gateway (Cybersource)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42719/coupon-calculates-but-doesnt-sent-correct-amount-to-payment-gateway-cybersourc) doesn't look like its going to be answered CORRECTLY. Now obviously a "correct" answered is determined by the person who asked the question. But in general, Does the bounty return to the issuer of an unanswered question or does it stick to the question eternally?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76137/bounty-with-no-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't accept any answer, or assign the bounty to any answer, and there aren't answers with a score of at least 2, the bounty is not awarded. As the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) says, in such case the bounty is not returned to who offered the bounty.

> In any case, you will *always* give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Comment: I think you should review this part. I'm happy to give a bounty to the right answer but if there are no good answers, I would like to have it back and maybe I may start a bounty giving more points. In this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52771/how-to-theme-a-menu-using-menu-tree-and-menu-link-region-by-region I offered 50points, none of the answers was the one I was looking for and now I would be happy to give 100points or 150points for bounty but if I don't get right answer I will loose up to 200points. Thanks

Comment: That is by design: Once a bounty is offered, the reputation spent for it is not returned. The reason behind this is that the purpose of a bounty is giving to a question more visibility; once you get that (which doesn't mean the question gets an answer that helps), you cannot take back the bounty, as that would mean getting attention for the question without _paying_ for the extra attention the question got.

Comment: If we cannot have the points back why don't you add a "renew bounty" or offer more points?

Comment: You can offer a new bounty, but the points spent for the previous bounty are not returned, even when the bounty has not been assigned. It would be too easy to use the bounty to get more attention for the question, and more reputation, if the points used for the bounty would be returned, when the bounty is not assigned.

Comment: I know what you mean and you are right. it's not easy to manage the bounty, everyone can start a bounty and not assign it to keep the reputation or something like this. So just keep the bounty a bit longer. Thanks